# Interleaving String

Tags: java, string

How I can mix two Strings in java?

If I have `abcde` and `123456789`, what is the simplest way to get `a1b2c3d4e56789`?

Here is my code :

```
public class Mix {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1="vera", s2="ronaldo"; /* input strings */

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
            sb.append(s1.charAt(i));
            sb.append(s2.charAt(i));
        }

        String result = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
vreornaa
```

My expected output:

```
vreornaaldo
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To complement @Rohit, you should also check which of the two string's length is longer, and append it to the result.

```
String s1 = "vera", s2 = "ronaldo";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

int minLength = Math.min(s1.length(), s2.length());
for (int i = 0; i < minLength; i++){
    sb.append(s1.charAt(i));
    sb.append(s2.charAt(i));
}

for (int i = minLength; i < s1.length(); i++){
    sb.append(s1.charAt(i));
}

for (int i = minLength; i < s2.length(); i++){
    sb.append(s2.charAt(i));
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Note that length check needs to be done before both the loops, and not just before this particular loop.

Comment: @Rohit, Now I realize that the code in the question don't check `s2` boundaries, I added a working solution.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. You just need to add another for loop to append the remaining part of the larger string. Just iterate the 2nd loop from smaller string length to larger string length:

```
for (int i = s1.length(); i < s2.length(); ++i) {
    sb.append(s2.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: what if s1.length() > s2.length() ?

Comment: @omainegra. I expect OP to find out which string is greater and approach accordingly. Is `s1.length() > s2.length()`, then the first loop itself will throw OutOfBoundsException.